# Render data in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, components, reactjs

I'm trying to learn ReactJS. In this HelloWorld script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>React JS Hello World</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/jsx">
    var data=[{name: "nthhtn", text: "Sample text"}];
    var DataBlock = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            var entry=this.props.data.map(function (entry){
                return (
                        <h3 name={entry.name}>
                        {entry.text}
                        </h3>
                );
            });
            return (
                    <div className="data" data={this.props.data}>
                            <h1>Sample data block</h1>
                    {entry}
                    </div>
            );
        }
    });
    React.render(
            <DataBlock data={data}/>,
            document.getElementById('content')
    );
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why when I run script in browser, the `name` field in `data` is not displayed, only the `text` field is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the data to getInitialState() check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bs65w2hs/

```
var data=[{name: "nthhtn", text: "Sample text"}];
var DataBlock  = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
        return {
            reactdata: data[0]  
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        var entrydata = this.state
        return <div>
                 <ul>
                   <li>name: {entrydata.reactdata.name}</li> 
                   <li>text: {entrydata.reactdata.text}</li>
                </ul>
               </div>
    }
 });

 React.render(<DataBlock />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are mixing things with same variable name "entry"

```
  render: function() {
            var entryBlock=this.props.data.map(function (entry){
                return (
                        <h3 name={entry.name}>
                        {entry.text}
                        </h3>
                );
            });
            return (
                    <div className="data" data={this.props.data}>
                            <h1>Sample data block</h1>
                    {entryBlock}
                    </div>
            );
        }
```

Change entry to entryBlock for example (see above code). If it's not that check that there is something in entry.text.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the question. It still doesn't work. The `text` is displayed, but the `name` is not

Comment: Have you changed what i've advised ?

Comment: what is in the name prop of h3 ? undefined ?

Comment: I posted all the source
Anyway, if I wrote like that, they would be displayed
`<h3>{entry.name}
                        {entry.text}
                        </h3>`
Thank you

Comment: I think this is a bad understanding of html. I thought you wanted to have you h3 div prop name set to entry.name

Comment: You're true, bro, I'm just a beginner, thanks anyway

Comment: No problem glad to help